# Blank page with basic setup

Tags: php, mpdf

i've got the problem that i'm using the basic setup given in the mpdf docs and only get a blank page as output.
ajax is working and debug output is the following:

```
debug: PDF generated in 0.013416 seconds
debug: Compiled in 0.039507 seconds
debug: Peak Memory usage 6.00 MB
debug: PDF file size 14 kB
debug: 2 fonts used
%PDF-1.4
```

rest of network response:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 132>>
stream
x�M�1�@�3߯x�.�4�=g�V��l�vz �9��S8$��H�@pr��!`u{Ũ��̌d��'�L��]����F�;#��@����,�%�kN@�a@'�F��a����t���E��4��[��q��>�{&]
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /ExtGState
/BM /Normal
/ca 1
/CA 1
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /MPDFAA+DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [7 0 R]
/ToUnicode 8 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /MPDFAA+DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold
/CIDSystemInfo 9 0 R
/FontDescriptor 10 0 R
/DW 540
/W [ 32 [ 313 395 469 754 626 855 813 275 426 426 470 754 313 374 313 329 ]
 48 57 626 58 59 332 60 62 754 63 [ 527 900 698 760 716 780 686 639 769 850 421 426 782 633 996 822 784 677 784 748 650 669 785 698 1011 698 642 657 426 329 426 754 450 450 583 629 548 629 572 387 629 654 342 325 624 342 952 654 600 629 629 474 506 416 654 523 774 536 523 511 579 327 579 754 ]
 ]
/CIDToGIDMap 11 0 R
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Length 346>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
1 beginbfrange
<0000> <FFFF> <0000>
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /MPDFAA+DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold
 /CapHeight 729
 /XHeight 519
 /FontBBox [-752 -389 1617 1145]
 /Flags 262148
 /Ascent 939
 /Descent -236
 /Leading 0
 /ItalicAngle 0
 /StemV 165
 /MissingWidth 540
 /Style << /Panose < 0 0 2 6 8 6 5 6 5 2 2 4> >>
/FontFile2 12 0 R
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Length 304
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x����V����Qfd%{dT*�l-�Ȉ��_���s��ڥ����}��@;��t���:��Nt�S�n�3�m�s��B��h��JW���nt�[��Nw�^�{��&�l�GM7�l�{���z��^4��^��7��]���B�-��J���V[�K�}�[}�G?��f���V���n���w��
endstream
endobj
12 0 obj
<</Length 11361
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length1 19964
>>
stream
x��|    |��oUW�dYH�@��B M�6Y�JȖIf&  $�af�!D6T6Q�5(*"���p�(*rq�p�n(rq!Sy��{&�����������=]�U�?��S=�#��Q"���dD���x�=�e�u:�W��Z�p�wT6�仿��B
<�i4W�}���W"_@��*�Ռ<�@��}�j��Y�����
�
:��m�"��ڠT5<�7{������5�8����WԚ*u��V#���W�t�f�S�W����\��3����+��C(��l��:�;ʞ��������c��K�����D�!�0@����(�TO���A�i:���׽E$*2j�В;;5�io���.|�������j�?|b~�]p�`�;;g�����=-"    i@k��y#���"�P
DA(�F!(��>����p4
~"P$�B�P4�b����a(
G�h�݆P"���(��nG��4݁ơ�hJA�(
���E�(e�4�<��
P!*B�P1*A�h2*CS�T4
t;�@3�,4�#�/ ��O8��5�� ;^=3p�-�ϵ���al �C��x��������q�SZ�Pp0-Fr���Ql���«��G�OG,�]g�U�6�G,2����Qxr
��h3��^�S8U�8wb
�^.`��}a�Ud\�3�� U�ü��  ���.]����\�Ч�ї�>���8�$
���x��I��!��W(�#��pv�;�*T�b�y�>@�9�F���>��H:O���g��E:��<&��?�t�4�h�`DI�"p��I$Fqr�A!:G0e�T�̴��q=n�� *:�g��tvM�I�J��hσbt�g����ܢ�����*��<��L�&����\�1q�=ChM���5i'�!kFFGF� u�!�u���<��b���Y�v^R�>(y�ĄАޚ����$$*�[}f���������f�����c|��d    ����jQ�x�Au\��ƵB~�W:�¸(�����!$Ψ�(v&E�l�q1e?L9=�wzq<F����p{��:��@�e����"��.�@�H�E켈�.���� �фA�xEɁ��X��F����8,0*�@����1��vhX�x48�`m��K|?}��W�G���Zi�r��u�����iy��Ϛ����^�7&{��9
���h��Пl�z��Ӈ�]C���ǉ+}J�e��w��L�8�| 䦸�K����>���A�I�Dj�|b�(F�i`7"Ga��0�qx͘��1cǴ>ܾ���ȧ�;�l!�ڟ}�����Ⱥ�U�v����ݻV�:u���O�z��_��^9u���W��;{�Ms����[<d7�c�q���޸��C��a�ax<N��D�c���hE���f6�d����
=�uW|�o��=m�T�W?䅷���~��^��/<万���o�\zWQF�>�uI���;�   �gXʋg��Ed<=����ϧ\���(���m��1�A��� �@�>��X�z�xjzC�Gx
@�!!0 (�x�7�?pN\�p�z��������r���{��r&=!<�`'�

b�D�5kMk���c�;�Ds9��x��7/�#�.8���!�h��  ���GtpT�3'K$�D�-�E�1���gg��4��G����1�{�m�L[��[���~���W�$�LI�y!zX�%E�Z��9G��%�q�+���+�_��}��`5Da��8�[��3k*ƻ�*}�2Ϗ�:el%�.lڙ>�!s�$�kB;���6v^�?�rF�=[l4df��ٙg�`cQg��j���OK~�c�X�%���(:aT`�`p����0�i6�
Kj��j�I�����}������s�����l��~^���XG�t%�������%&%JI�C�<  �w��#G6~��J;�cg��~ oT�x�(�,'����<(
�����b=Fx��O�J���c�iԹwq˜6Q�Ӣ�������҉W:���;��ZE�m �j�
�����Y�#"ǰ̤�0��4��G���O����M����_�������+7nY{ǈ��Z�,��EE�8�|O���O��ɐ!8{�ƽ[=ؼb���Y��=�����b.f��
LāX|�����M!����l�Vr���b�^/\pSdxdh[�>ǔ��Bz��p��ǭw�7�7,�O�����Z͢K�Zi���)]��#�#�?�J2g޿���O���&\b��tv��@��0#d����<�Nz�k�c�O>���*��~Y~Ԥ��ԅ�V�Xwffa�����a�Hz��_�/x6����ߌ5W�����>�N�*q�艐�+���q���sBGMyW�x=V|���K���*�aP+�`U/7�<ș&)f&N&AA�nm2m�n�
�
���<�z5FW�h�����������RcuqI����?��~���g��]r�̙cK���MM۷54o�����W�]    <��1�}5 �)$�D����&�@;3@K�c�O~�;�q���}m�s��Z���I-Nu|���}��
��5t�������_@{/�N���n�!Э�W����geU*�L=^h�WPP_�8��A�X��c�� q���<���p:%���}����4)S<    ��%��$,i;֒y��K�y�=x��9>�uw�2aϢ�L,��yR\�__(\�]B�1��0��<r�'z����˸��5u^"_q[DB~�.���a��5x�!3�`��4�h���K�|�a����s=�\U״�ȏ^��?�^�Æټ���K���N�j��v��XLrs�f���
��T6<�<4BH�0��alܠ���#Aɣ���aX���O���6�<dqQ��S�E���Z|o���Ӆ
�M^tϔ"����_��h�}��C����bŃ�߁=����������۞ܰ������~:�r^V��o̷�~[^P���C���B04��H�UZ�p��{�8�غp���D�x�~Oς��?C
����PTR",*P?&%��#�ÿ�q_os���D=�� x�9�4㏝v;����Q�X�7�
_z
p� �R�(`�(qL�   9��(ko'�׮����w�yz��-�?ܸx������K�#�/��;�՝�M����4^��ەܙ�yI���n4�3��j.c���43���
�O`6�   ��,Q�?x�رW����}�)~ y=��J׿x��D�����=�I?���Y��a+�)���o�r�|����v�i<*�6����,���@M {D7�E�o�90�\:�g��fWP�xd��5\��Bw�-c�Eq��q̱�"ݡ�aI�rc����D��x2 �?�g�ݩǍ��p�9��M���!����ɣ��.Iz�=��1��;���"z�)�q�Azr�`���Oގ�q
�����Y�v��\<���
�r�T9B��8��������N��5��z��.�[�.L���[n�Ne��c;���D�XȂ$I]d�<�,o�23�d�"�m�������fM���4�n���_>��&Cwz�_�X��.F��מ��ºe�v�>��'BH���j��v'��
`�uӋ�
(p�"����*n7�<�ƃ�R!����߿��s���vP"����g8i�עh�~Y�����$�+0�]�Xe��Mjo�;ɰ����w���\������;Ҕw)̟~��AY�(N�^����ݻ���ٳ�e!���u.���p.��i�(}��G�x+�����!�6Q�+.��PѸ2
T"�-!�-��ϰ'���k�ghXuO��1���3�i/�p���u�9�t-�7{�&
��Sb�����   B��v�������u�}���
����;�~��F�N�����N�E���a�x��=sQ"�d�D;�"o�Ǿrͼ8~J~�G���-�|��N��+6
��͘B��������L䷎o}6��ի7q_�CMs
�U��
�쬱�����",r�K���W�W��o�v`�ˍ�s����ǖ��u��G�@�u�.ڑ�+��j�ܩ�|��#�Go^[e���<������C�I9|�A<ޝ$�O�u-���t�!�x�{�@W}}�#`�r�-lO��2�-ȷ`��[�[H�ێ=�u?~��^��t�^�f@؅�~���6���Gx0��r¿Ե�u`m�5�����f*��J���%`����v��E>����y�)�$�Mq΍�RZ��o`O��7�m�кc���فw�#N�~�c���Fv��|�I��<Gz)��WK�$��(̣�<N�v�
:�Eغ�X؆��E��9*6
�ȓcQ:Ê��Ƒĉp��$�o�0����q�R�EX��b��x���z֎��ia4|�9>P�̀����]J��7z$���"���Z�ݲZ|�\��z�[t�2�+zE�R�[�y��
w?N��w��o4����vO���������1���+������5���Y��c^ {�B���=3l�??Ni�q�O��<KO   �9=N6����L6w���F��J���Ga<����A�����</�B\��(
a�0#9kű��4��CqR׶�וt�-��o��ҞzkyU���9#�?җ���gfM�SX��޾����Ǟyz��)�_FF����B�����C��K��:��f��7y<e
�6�s�¨>����p����V���3��+��*�'ۥ�fǽ%��z�w&�,�c��~�哻^�:`2������ 캽�b��ŀ��;��\ӟ�1�[����/(o��y�������x�С���w����sm�N�}r�29��ܒS�Jy��%E���ٕE�*f��   +��!�^��?_3�3�ßԼ���/�<��ݾ�d�c�ࡓJpG��RA�M�±���h)�    �2'g    �9���ڂ6�|����W���0����N5y���|۳�����\�o��5���QP��]k4��&�,0xd��N��#��+֬y�T�}��wA�u�J{�kv;I�/{��`�7-~|Dq�ǔ�j!3��"��0I,���?�_�2���6ػԅO��NM�':�?�WD�1n;mwW�r;ݬ��E6)d�=�M�*�Bn&�X�_�����+�����i�n�:���������l�O���a|�\Vպ�S�k9�k�a�����Ԋ��T:�d�Th�������&:Z9΀�8l�PJ��$e���C?1������F�O3
Ic�F2Xs��}��3��;�s\�5���E 8�ߢ�b�J��P8����B� �^b��>}
�_���L���4�q^l�_s���T�T���3N��؎�)��Q���Lu��
��V��Ο���*�N�R�W�ɹ�gZYn�)��iF#y]e�}�>Gw�-f|�t���W�[��M3�*�z�9�U���v?`87r5>�n�w��5.���j}�$�����`�2<�~ZzVX��    J_�e�{�Xz��N��존L|   �}Q��n�1�ɿ3w*R�+�IOtK��;_)dר�����I��O�=���������
Ǯ��*B����Il&A�a���w�J^���c����n>�w�}������Eb"=9���t7���zq�,�DN�7��u�֋,�ʌ~�m����wm\��g�_j0z��t�1�K^\���ig�ئ��̔̾ѱ-9�w`�ZW�M5>$:i�C�p�q@;W��߀E��!{�䖥'=�j��7�6d�d�n��N�K������Ѱ*����W>Xl��b�Y�ՙǮ�xh�
��(~�ό-�M��1Ŋ�
���_����j���;n���1B��~j���5B���ϭ��D;vG��j�b䬿4Sa.�_�9+��Y?������b�<����}�~\-���?��X!���F�zB8��o�E�׏�&�(y�G�+��a�U���pˡCm�q%�?��m�.�    ��2�    �Շ~����&��֝�k����̞p7х   ��W�զ�qw���OgW  1�_.-�U��*BC>���*�E(D��g͛>�����L�i�\��x�k'��aM��;����i��r(��vj1�xv���֨���B@y�LM:�~gC\���E�ɋ�C��mx���l�S&.�o?����V���?�u��nk���^yx��ȥӟ���?�p|P��~������[n��M�=�¸W)�U�BAq�P�)lAK���j�t}�Ԧ�;s�ӗ��ax�P���䅺о�7���¬�׶�#�؎�W�j�m\t����A�o��Q�))�L��K3���dUgB�'����{�O^��S�y�vӔ)��,[��u��2፲�1B���7�L�A4ي�!�M�~�ڻm�{��/4Г���    ;��_��{�+�z"����������^VO��W!��<5�s1xB,��GOj<Q�$��4Q��
�#ѓ��s&9��@�I�Gp�J�n/�=5����g��p>�
��pΆ�R؃��9�a8O�v�䑈�Ҧ�+��9��5�����L3�_Ged�՝vM<@e���
h�F��90�]�CÚ�zk���������    yIQpME �W�g�.�/���`��x�DC�
~�7�\������v�E4A���,:�
m��� ���c��k(I�C���A�PqD�'��Οĉ�)Ft~#����Y؎~��n&?� T=F��h    z˸ߍ�@E���-�B��!K��3DC��Yd+�ǈ�^o�_�j�u��� �DM�f��
��[=�=,<^���3�����e��|�FyU{�������Y����z�A��K����Ƨ�O��
�C>��z����������W~������������"�6���g{y�
�U�k�������p��/��^�7O��*��w��lt\mc�Զ�Dlr���nW�"�'�I�W��5��Im{�@�Y���    Q�~^���m4R�R��Wޤ���|��*Kd��1N��a-Ĳ��'6�m�Fa���}FmK�ն%�j�E
�ն#�V�~��I���G�?R����@m���c(��ّՠ*T�lH�o%�2J���V�-�{*����iA�Cu�o�Q�����JE�pȨ؅e�w�`N#|�a�7ʀ�@(C
0����������e@��O3���'�|���>o��Mf�����&���n�5Q���i56��b����9���rjm�\�FY�b��`i4��3ste
re����`�u�\S/�*jk*e��NWS�sZ��AFh3��?��rɐ
Yb���tS��Po5��4Z���j��{�r�����s�e�
8&n���e*3X�5�z9!>qdw�]��LvxO������  b�(�#�T�s2m4ՃAm`fĝ��2��C�b4F<�5���c�x�h�k�9��f3�1B��
�VS���`4Y�����t�����s@�>&����5�&�����ӳ��!e�\:h�����K��F��EҸ���d�Q�(�~��:�չ���C��0Ɋ8^G�r|���T��8�z�z�c�5���q�L��z>߬�B��6��5�+Y*UM;1m���q��Q��C�*���VxW<���Z�n^�-���ʮV�W%�ѩ�)>X   ^Y�Ql�ǩ#�jU?�ⱋKH�Ă��b�N�3|��J糋=���}�zm��I�)ĩ�T  �5pE'M��yN�������%r�[�y��m�a��uX����i����츿�#�%���d��ă�]�j���o.�Ss
�f�G�zx]�DM\u�g4yN�W%4�Q��OF#�_��
 ��5�ݏk�,�P��rԸ�a��΢�T��D�]6p�E]�s&���65���:c�Kc�9�}��e֩��p�m��)�P2��&�4�5HVm_ǯ]��?��
$7�uM�J�MS7��tbw�_ǣ��ǲ3�1�mj�S�(�2���l��u���QQ��(:>�)��s��U轢*Ǥ�V�Y�r��{��N=�c��2��8}7�q݈��sҝ^O�܈�8��|^�M��E�@�_]7\���3�q�s1�����M\*=�y�u1�%w�l�sՍt�6%v�z�3<�Mn�6���D#���@c���\�F�e���jp�p�����#��gz�_�*��Q�/�t7�ᬷA�t��u#��n�s��7f�j=-��8��Q���u� uFwD3���Y�ZLY�n{��믥�PcĦ��F������)Dp���])��d1�ˁg2�s��Sw�ep����ɣq
�b!�̱�b�d���    Ö�=�˅����j�TNCh%|d1�·�ypժ�،tx2�Y;�jT����S)�6��pZ
ϻ�v�*�Str�wŀ����b����q\S�]��3S�4��!3�t�(�߱���Z�J�>S��
�\�L�Wd�rK(���5��`�ȫ�s�(��#㸄L�>�Q��O�
U+�vJ��K���2�.2����32f�T�w�:}'�#��h2�/�롐SH�}L�L�y���nVI��bvc�gpJ�\#%7�ĉ��:7�'�,.��k*��.=ja|���9\�tU�
����O�i7���,;   �jU�J��.�!��.)����n:�~�j�t�����Y+Sx,j��Tn��2y�櫜Ov�0�'��Y�⬻~�q�����I��3�?������q�ܥ�u���wl���}�v���R��3�-׺WJ��c�z��z��ge�����p7Z���d���~�Շ��\���կ���J-huU%��arU&M��kMWv�u|��~���*�5�3zb)���W���ڼ�
�s�h��B���mje��kPǲ��{�-=vU��NY���-��fuOU�5���xׂ���.�0
(o��zX����Գe:�r�\�Z\y��hz#��_Ʊ���E���<�j0��ZSSl���r����\f��d����{�M���������k�E�f��
u:�\�d���]d���X��P]m��V�EWo3��d���i ���'�L���.�
+L0U�@���*�R    L���j��^SWYi�3�p6�V
�$��T�U`zYg��*kt@4X�Pg���l�cM-�xC�����:���Xf�I�Pi�0�����f�<t�V��m�3N�jlզ0SW�b�-�*��
�8qr��K��k��s��h�0Yd���k�UU��skf����ㄚ�Mu���`l��A��7�VS�lm��c���'��k�%�@��z}
��:�ۻ�t�F�@�"΀� �M60�Uyʬb���O�V�@�
��5`�\�MNS=��E�3Y7[�����+Lu���~�I_c�a������A@uz=�\Q�/��j��Y8!��ZSU�٨�����l�P]%�X�'?֞���+
�պ�Q�9y�B�k�rM7W�,�?V�cY�ʔ�l���A��d�[�HW,F2��9��n$WX'O��
DCm;0!M5.��6�Yg6C��*j
�C��{�Zg��uV@4�w����p��P�W��W"  ofY���E673�N�e��9Ь����� �M���;V7R���EC��1���3J����)��Z9�D.*.,���fȑ�%p'O�)�.�\*È�Ԃ�ira��Z0M��)Ȉ��S���%%ra���_����g9�y�3r
��4�WPX*����hi!��B�hKX��8=nS�r�rJ��ə9�3@S���Ҝ��y��r����-`dlANAf1P��kAJ/,�V���]�J�a�\Z����O-΍c���2\��-c�K�S��䴜Ғ�bmj>˴�UP��t4� #�4��@Nӂ(�iyZ�7%=/5'?N�H�O�Җta�Tq���&di�ũyqrI�6=�5@�9���R>t�����h'M�0�I���$@�T�/�s��/qNiaq���)9%�89�8����Y\�2{�&�d�'3^��/�{�g�Ql�*`�65Kޥm�4�m̷��V�#O�J���^�$p�z\�o�?Cd�G�p]�Ŗ�85�����`Uӯ��Y��R ć�%��+�tX�L�g��1���RWӬ.6��sA4[j`J����D�5�SK�|u)��KUO    ���[V3�T5��Z{<�����sRSo4Y�Tѹ�*mc�9�&Wqp=n�T����'ߊ��U�\8G��Q�����w�fx��=�ͿC�T3�fD
���xs�y�����;�n�J�����;k���s!�����Ж��9J��%�Sr֛�͟�I ���W��S�W6��)9A���,r�V�_��Er��(y��#��ao�l94�<�M�I�~���T_r�ɾ���ɾ䉇��'���� ��d�ٷ7Pڗ@���m�x�{�i7%��v��ǃ��ǆI;���l��c�ȣpy�(ydG_�Jv�%���ێJ�)ٶu���(��&n�-m�I���[mK4��P��y�|��xJ��P yЗ<�">N6�����?r�-��z�>J���z�n����7Y�C֦�kV�Ikz��~��U�ҽ   d�7�'��\�*��d�X�J��!���p�4�ܵ$X���%�zIK�I�"?���E~dQ��F,��u�@���I���R%��3��G��6��-�g{��M��I#�h�K�����+%@�P2���&�M�S<������27���&ՔTy���A�DOI��ʹ��(ѵ�rJf���>����L$Ӧ�Kӆ���dJ)�!�%}��M��/)�K&�J��I��TJ
�RF
��K�$?�O��O�Sļ^����H.t�&���|b+��#�Y�Rv+��&�Z?)3�h3|%��*&��%�i}��M$�IM�R[I�(/)ş�����J���p?���b�c�Hw��c���}Ș��Ҙ 2ڛܞ�K���$���^$�M�EF��I#�HI���a^��>$�+\J�Db��Jn�'���H� #�J#�I|��?����o"q0'.�ĥ�ü������p�GbS�!1�ҐM$����q�'���dPp�4(�D�%��H��D"dO)D���'�Sā�;p(I94 p�4`    � �[I��7�ܒ@�@wJ�Bc���$�BcI��-� ���`Prp  ��A�$D
N@;��^���o�@8�?���M}zo�}�x�O�`��(�&���&�7�RD�Ib�D�{I$��Q��@��6�|뗭�����C����G�$T�t
endstream
endobj
2 0 obj
<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F2 6 0 R
>>
/ExtGState <<
/GS1 5 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<<
/Producer (��mPDF 8.2.2)
/CreationDate (D:20240126233057+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20240126233057+00'00')
>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
/OpenAction [3 0 R /XYZ null null 1]
/PageLayout /OneColumn
>>
endobj
xref
0 15
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000425 00000 n 
0000013884 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000223 00000 n 
0000000514 00000 n 
0000000575 00000 n 
0000000731 00000 n 
0000001276 00000 n 
0000001671 00000 n 
0000001739 00000 n 
0000002058 00000 n 
0000002434 00000 n 
0000014000 00000 n 
0000014132 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 15
/Root 14 0 R
/Info 13 0 R
/ID [<25ad9a4692df4ea155ad5a9b595c25f9> <25ad9a4692df4ea155ad5a9b595c25f9>]
>>
startxref
14242
%%EOF
```

here is my code:

pdfgenerator.php

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

function generatePDF($data) {

    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    try {
        $mpdf = new Mpdf();
        $mpdf->setLogger(new class extends \Psr\Log\AbstractLogger {
            public function log($level, $message, array $context = [])
            {
                echo $level . ': ' . $message . "\n";
            }
        });
        $mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1 style='color: black;'>Hello world</h1>");
        $mpdf->Output();
    } catch (\Mpdf\MpdfException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Überprüfe, ob das Ziel 'generatePDF' ist
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_TARGET'] === 'generatePDF') {
        $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $pdfData = generatePDF($postData);
        echo $pdfData;
        exit;
    }
}

header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
```

index.html

```
<script>
function apiRequest(data, funct, successCallBack, errorCallBack) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader('target', funct);
            },
            url: "pdfgenerator.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (respond) {
                successCallBack(respond);
            },
            error: function (respond, status, error) {
                errorCallBack(respond, status, error);
            }
        });
    }
    function generatePDF() {
        apiRequest(requestData, 'generatePDF', function (pdfData) {
            var blob = new Blob([pdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            downloadLink.download = 'pdffile.pdf';
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }, function (error) {
        });

    }
</script>
```

after six hours i can't find any solution. tried with multiple setups, including the html as a template.php file and so on

Comment: `generatePDF()` doesn't use its `$data` parameter.

Comment: Also, vendor/autoload.php should always be before any "use" statements.

Comment: The `generatePDF()` PHP function returns nothing, so `$pdfData` is null and `echo $pdfData;` has no effect.

Comment: And why are you using AJAX? You don't need AJAX to download a file. Just submit a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Oliver - changed it to a normal html form and it's working fine.
pdfgenerator.php is now the following.

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Mpdf\Mpdf;
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf=8" />
            <title>Muttizettel</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome '. $_POST["name-u18"] . '
</body>
</>';

$mpdf = new Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
```